iPhone15 simulator, unable to type spaces into edit fields
I have an iphone 15 simulator running. In any text entry/edit field, when I try to type a space at the end of the field it does not register it and prevents any other typing into that field.
I can see this when manually using it and I can see it when its part of an Appium automated test.
I can use the left arrow on the keyboard at the of a string of text, go back a few and insert a space. Just for some reason it wont let me type space at the end of entry fields.
Any ideas on how to resolve this?.
Edit1: Have tried with iPhone14 simulator and the same problem occurs.
This is running iOS 17.2 on a M2 laptop.
Edit2: It would appear that this might be an issue to do with the latest MacOS version (Apple M2 Pro + Sonoma 14.5), as other people I know with different operating systems do not have this issue, but one other person with the same OS does!. Anyone able to confirm this is an issue for them or not using such a setup?
